# Mail with only post data filled (php mailer)

Tags: php, post, phpmailer

I've got a form with nine tables that have quantities to be filled, and then there's a button - on the bottom of the page - that gets to an other page, where there are personal infos to be filled and there is a summary of the tables with the chosen quantities.
I'd like to send an email (I'm using PHPmailer) in which - in addition to the personal infos form - ONLY the tables with at least one filled $POST are visible, while the others are invisible.

How could I do that?

Comment: your question is a bit unclear. you should use php sessions

Comment: I used sessions to store data from the POST and in the second page you can visualize only the tables in which one or more POST are being filled.
This is the page: http://www.bendana.it/it/acquisti.php